# Ensure executables called in Go Process get killed when Process is killed

Tags: go

I have some code that in Go (golang), has a few different threads running a separate executable. I want to ensure that if a user kills my process in Go, that I have a way of killing the executables I've called, is there a way to do that?

Comment: In same fashion that you start the process you can kill it using the Bash command of your choosing (like killall) and the `exec` package. Just create a clean up function and call it with `defer` in your main.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal: a defer doesn't run when you receive a signal, since the function isn't returning. You need a signal handler to catch it.

Comment: Tangentially related but worth linking to: [killing a whole process group on Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/q/392022/720999).

Answer (score 18):

The only ways to ensure that the child process is killed, is to start it in the same process group, and kill the process group as a whole, or set `Pdeadthsig` in the [`syscall.SetProcAttr`](https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/#SysProcAttr).

You can setup a signal handler for common signals like `SIG_INT` and `SIG_TERM`, and kill your child processes before exiting, but since you can't catch `SIG_KILL` that's often not worth the effort.

See: [Panic in other goroutine not stopping child process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34095254/panic-in-other-goroutine-not-stopping-child-process/34095869#34095869)

```
cmd := exec.Command("./long-process")

cmd.SysProcAttr = &syscall.SysProcAttr{
    Pdeathsig: syscall.SIGTERM,
}
```

Comment: note that the syscall package is deprecated as of Go 1.4 (see https://golang.org/s/go1.4-syscall) and you're supposed to use https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/sys - I think Prctl is the method that gives you the equivalent behaviour

Comment: @Nick, that's incorrect. The syscall package is mostly frozen, but not "deprecated". Much of the stdlib depends on it.

Comment: The document says "We can freeze and, in effect, deprecate it, however." Maybe the document should be edited to clarify what people are supposed to do

Comment: @Nick, that was just the proposal document, from when the syscall "freeze" was implemented. It's not official documentation, and is out of date.

Comment: However, the Pdeathsig _is_ deprecated

Comment: @Rambatino, do you have reference for that? I can't find anything in offcial documentation or source code that says its deprecated.

Comment: I've just had a look at the source code, and I too cannot find where I got that from. But I would have come across it having commented on here.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Windows, you might find this snippet helpful:

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "unsafe"

    "golang.org/x/sys/windows"
)

// We use this struct to retreive process handle(which is unexported)
// from os.Process using unsafe operation.
type process struct {
    Pid    int
    Handle uintptr
}

type ProcessExitGroup windows.Handle

func NewProcessExitGroup() (ProcessExitGroup, error) {
    handle, err := windows.CreateJobObject(nil, nil)
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }

    info := windows.JOBOBJECT_EXTENDED_LIMIT_INFORMATION{
        BasicLimitInformation: windows.JOBOBJECT_BASIC_LIMIT_INFORMATION{
            LimitFlags: windows.JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_KILL_ON_JOB_CLOSE,
        },
    }
    if _, err := windows.SetInformationJobObject(
        handle,
        windows.JobObjectExtendedLimitInformation,
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&info)),
        uint32(unsafe.Sizeof(info))); err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }

    return ProcessExitGroup(handle), nil
}

func (g ProcessExitGroup) Dispose() error {
    return windows.CloseHandle(windows.Handle(g))
}

func (g ProcessExitGroup) AddProcess(p *os.Process) error {
    return windows.AssignProcessToJobObject(
        windows.Handle(g),
        windows.Handle((*process)(unsafe.Pointer(p)).Handle))
}

func main() {
    g, err := NewProcessExitGroup()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer g.Dispose()

    cmd := exec.Command("notepad.exe", "noname")
    if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    if err := g.AddProcess(cmd.Process); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    if err := cmd.Wait(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Original link: https://gist.github.com/hallazzang/76f3970bfc949831808bbebc8ca15209

Answer (score 1):

One possible strategy is to keep a list of processes you're running in a global array `var childProcesses = make([]*os.Process, 0)` and append to it every time you start a process.

Have your own `Exit` function. Make sure that you never call `os.Exit` anywhere in your code, and always call your own `Exit` function instead. Your Exit function will kill all the `childProcesses`

```
for _, p := range childProcesses {
    p.Kill()
}
```

Handle signals so they go through your own exit function, for example by doing this during initialization (somewhere near the top of your main function)

```
sigs := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
signal.Notify(sigs, syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM, syscall.SIGKILL, syscall.SIGQUIT)
goUnsafe(func() {
    var signal = <-sigs
    log.Println("Got Signal", signal)
    Exit(0)
})
```

Comment: What is 'goUnsafe'?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use unix.Prctl.

```
flag := unix.SIGHUP
if err := unix.Prctl(unix.PR_SET_PDEATHSIG, uintptr(flag), 0, 0, 0); err != nil {
    return
}
```

A detailed example is below, new.go for child process and main.go as parent process.

```
//new.go
package main

func main() {
    flag := unix.SIGHUP

    if err := unix.Prctl(unix.PR_SET_PDEATHSIG, uintptr(flag), 0, 0, 0); err != nil {
    return
    }

    f, _ := os.Create("./dat2")
    defer f.Close()
    i := 0
    for {
        n3, _ := f.WriteString("writes " + string(i) + "\n")
        fmt.Printf("wrote %d bytes\n", n3)
        f.Sync()
        i += 2
        time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
    }

    for {
        n3, _ := f.WriteString("newwrites\n")
        fmt.Printf("wrote %d bytes\n", n3)
        f.Sync()
        time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
    }
}


//main.go
package main

import "os/exec"

func main() {
    commandA := exec.Command("./new")
    commandA.Start()
    commandB := exec.Command("./new")
    commandB.Start()
    for {
    }
}
```

Comment: You are mistaken -- `Pdeathsig` is still in Go's Linux `SysProcAttr`.

Comment: The `unix` package being used in the example code comes from here: https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/sys/unix

Comment: Note that this answer only applies if the *children* processes are written in golang, since they have to be changed to call unix.Prctl on themselves.

Comment: Note that the death-signal stuff is not implemented in all Unix variants.

Answer (score 0):

> I have some code that in Go (golang), has a few different threads running a separate executable. I want to ensure that if a user kills my process in Go, that I have a way of killing the executables I've called, is there a way to do that?

It is not clear to me what you mean by "different threads running."  I will assume:

- Those threads belong to "executables I've called"
- Those threads have not necessarily written in golang
- You cannot control their execution (i.e., you unable to change their code)

In this sense, we are talking about to create a process group and ensure that when you kill a process, every other process in that group must stop too.  This mechanism is Operating System dependent.

In the current version, there are two possibilities (see package [x/sys](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/sys)):

- **Unix**: it is about to [`setpgid(2)`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/sys/unix#Setgid)
- **Windows**: it is about to [`CreateProcess`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/sys/windows#CreateProcess).  Please, refer to the [MS Windows documentation CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa?redirectedfrom=MSDN).  You must pass the `CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP` flag ([see](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-process-groups))

Comment: `setgid` is for the group ID of the running process, as distinguished from the *process* group to which the process belongs. That is, files have uid-and-gid and this gid is a file-gid, not a process-group-ID.

Comment: @torek, you are alright.  I did a type when wrote this; I mean `setpgid(2)`.  Just corrected it in my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Much better - note that you not only need to use `setpgid` but also need to make sure that whatever is sending the signal is doing it with the process group IDs and `killpg`. (But that's up to whatever is *sending* the signal, i.e., there's not too much you can do in your own Go program.)