# kill child process - exec.Command

Tags: go

How do you kill child processes?

I have a long running application starting a new process with "exec.Command":

```
// ...I am a long running application in the background

// Now I am starting a child process, that should be killed togeter with the parent application.
cmd := exec.Command("sh", "-c", execThis)

// create a new process group
// cmd.SysProcAttr = &syscall.SysProcAttr{Setpgid: true}
```

Now if I kill `<pid of long running application in the background>` it does not kill the child process - do you know how?

Comment: But why the child process should be killed if parent killed?

Comment: I am handeling fswatch application events within my application(running in the background), and I need both to be killed when killing the parent

Comment: Handle `sigterm` and `sigint` signals in your application, and kill children process in signal handler. I think you can do nothing with kill 9 (`sigkill`).

Comment: Thanks I will try killing the main application using signals, and then handle the child accordingly.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34730941/ensure-executables-called-in-go-process-get-killed-when-process-is-killed/34731014#34731014

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are quite a few things to be teased apart here.

First, there's what the OS itself does.  Then, once we know what the OS is and what it does, there's what the *program* does.

What the OS does is, obviously, OS-dependent.  POSIX-flavored OSes have two kinds of `kill` though: plain `kill` and process-group-based `kill`, or [`killpg`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/killpg.html).  The killpg variety of this function is the only one that sends a signal to an entire process *group;* plain `kill` just sends a signal to a single *process*.

When a program is run from a [*controlling terminal*](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap11.html), *keyboard signals* (^C, ^Z, etc) get sent to the *foreground process group* of that control terminal (see the linked page for a reasonably good description of these and note that BSD/macOS has ^T and `SIGINFO` as well).  But if the signals are being sent from some other program, rather than from a controlling terminal, it is up to that program whether to call `killpg` or `kill`, and what signal(s) to send.

Some signals *cannot* be caught.  This is the case for SIGKILL and SIGSTOP.  These signals should not be sent [willy-nilly](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/willy-nilly); they should be reserved to a last resort.  Instead, programs that want another program to stop should generally send one of SIGINT, SIGTERM, SIGHUP, or (rarely) SIGQUIT.  Go tends to tie SIGQUIT to debug (in that the runtime on POSIX systems makes ^\ dump the stacks of the various goroutines) so that one is not a good choice.  However, it's not up to the Go program you write here, which can only try to *catch* the signal.  The choice of what to send is up to the sender.

The "Go way" to *catch* the signal is to use a goroutine and a channel.  The [`signal.Notify`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/signal/#Notify) function turns an OS-level signal into an event on the channel.  What you do not (and cannot) know is whether the signal reached *your* process through `kill` or `killpg` (though if it came from a controlling terminal interaction, the POSIX-y kernel sent it via the equivalent of `killpg`).  If you want to propagate that signal on your own, simply use the notification event to invoke code that makes an OS-level `kill` call.  When using [the `os/exec` package](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/), use [`cmd.Process.Signal`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Process.Signal): note that this invokes the POSIX `kill`, not its `killpg`, but you would not want to use `killpg` here since we're assuming a non-process-group signal in the first place (a pgroup-based signal presumably needs no propagation).

There is no fully portable way to send a signal to a POSIX process group (which is not surprising, since this isn't portable to non-POSIX systems).  Sadly, there's no direct Unix or POSIX specific way to do that either, it seems, in Go.

On non-POSIX systems, everything is quite different.  See the discussion near the front of [the `os/signal` package](https://golang.org/pkg/os/signal/).