# In Golang, how to terminate an os.exec.Cmd process with a SIGTERM instead of a SIGKILL?

Tags: linux, go, ubuntu, process, operating-system

Currently, I am terminating a process using the Golang **os.exec.Cmd.Process.Kill()** method (on an Ubuntu box).

This seems to terminate the process immediately instead of gracefully. Some of the processes that I am launching also write to files, and it causes the files to become truncated.

I want to terminate the process gracefully with a **SIGTERM** instead of a **SIGKILL** using Golang.

Here is a simple example of a process that is started and then terminated using cmd.Process.Kill(), I would like an alternative in Golang to the Kill() method which uses SIGTERM instead of SIGKILL, thanks!

```
import "os/exec"

cmd := exec.Command("nc", "example.com", "80")
if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil {
   log.Print(err)
}
go func() {
  cmd.Wait()
}()
// Kill the process - this seems to kill the process ungracefully
cmd.Process.Kill()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66640617/4466350

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [Signal()](https://pkg.go.dev/os#Process.Signal) API. The supported [Syscalls](https://pkg.go.dev/syscall#SIGTERM) are here.

So basically you might want to use

```
cmd.Process.Signal(syscall.SIGTERM)
```

Also please note as per documentation.

> The only signal values guaranteed to be present in the os package on
> all systems are os.Interrupt (send the process an interrupt) and
> os.Kill (force the process to exit). On Windows, sending os.Interrupt
> to a process with os.Process.Signal is not implemented; it will return
> an error instead of sending a signal.

Answer (score 2):

```
cmd.Process.Signal(syscall.SIGTERM)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use:

```
cmd.Process.Signal(os.Interrupt)
```

Tested example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("nc", "-l", "8080")
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    cmd.Stdin = os.Stdin
    err := cmd.Start()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        err := cmd.Wait()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("cmd.Wait:", err)
        }
        fmt.Println("done")
        wg.Done()
    }()

    fmt.Println("TCP Dial")
    fmt.Println("Pid =", cmd.Process.Pid)
    time.Sleep(200 * time.Millisecond)
    // or comment this and use: nc 127.0.0.1 8080
    w1, err := net.DialTimeout("tcp", "127.0.0.1:8080", 1*time.Second)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("tcp DialTimeout:", err)
    }
    defer w1.Close()

    fmt.Fprintln(w1, "Hi")
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    // cmd.Process.Kill()
    cmd.Process.Signal(os.Interrupt)
    wg.Wait()
}
```

Output:

```
TCP Dial
Pid = 21257
Hi
cmd.Wait: signal: interrupt
done
```

Comment: I needed SIGTERM, so syscall.SIGTERM did the trick for my use case, but this is also a fantastic answer, os.Interrupt will also be very useful in some scenarios, thank you for the example.